# Is there a way to call a function inside another function?

Tags: javascript, file, scope, filereader

I have the following code :

```
var f1 = document.getElementById("f"), 
f1 = function () {
var rd1 = new FileReader();
rd1.onload = function () {
              
             function assign () { 
                toto = function toto() {
                     // Code there
             }


        rd1.readAsBinaryString(f1.files[0]);
    }; 
f1.addEventListener('change', rd1);
```

What I want is to be able to call the function toto() outside of this above block. Is there a way to do that or the scope doesn't allow it ?

Answer (score 1):

Function declarations are scoped to the function they are defined in.

To access them outside, you need to explicitly assign them somewhere.

For example:

```
let toto = null;

function assign() {
     toto = function toto () { ... };
}
```

… however, scope aside, you are trying to call the function **before** it has been created as per the classic [asynchronous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) so  you'll need to rethink your approach.

Comment: I see, and by the way you did, how at the end do you call the toto function ?

Comment: `todo()` (at a point in time **after** `assign()` has been called)

Comment: But in my case it would have been called inside the block by doing so, no ?

Comment: Yes (which makes assigning it outside the block pointless).